# Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true. Failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, deployment, continuous-integration, travis-ci, github-pages

I am working on a react-weather application for self learning purpose.
Deployed the same in gh-pages. 
URL 
**https://davisraimon.github.io/react-weather/** 
Repo 
**https://github.com/davisraimon/react-weather** 
When tried to integrate my application with **Travis Ci**, i got error as follows.
It says like i have to change some env variable called Process.env.CI.

```
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://github.com/davisraimon/react-weather.git davisraimon/react-weather
nvm.install
4.18s$ nvm install stable
cache.1
Setting up build cache
cache.npm
$ node --version
v14.4.0
$ npm --version
6.14.5
$ nvm --version
0.35.3
install.npm
13.21s$ npm ci 
7.45s$ npm run build
> react-weather@0.1.0 build /home/travis/build/davisraimon/react-weather
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
Most CI servers set it automatically.
Failed to compile.
./src/components/form.component.js
  Line 1:17:  'Component' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
./src/App.js
  Line 2:8:    'logo' is defined but never used              no-unused-vars
  Line 8:7:    'API_key' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 37:5:   Expected a default case                       default-case
  Line 53:14:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='           eqeqeq
  Line 69:20:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='           eqeqeq
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-weather@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-weather@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/travis/.npm/_logs/2020-06-30T17_45_07_887Z-debug.log
The command "npm run build" exited with 1.
cache.2
store build cache
```

I added env variable in .travis.yml file.

```
env:
    process.env.CI : false
```

Still its showing the same error.

Can anyone help me out of this situation please...

Comment: Yes....When i do that it will work perfectly. Thanks

Comment: For future readers `process.env` is the node variable that contains all environment variables. In the `.travis.yml` file, you should just use the variable name, in this case `CI`, without the `process.env`.

Answer (score 89):

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI=false && react-scripts build",  // Add CI=False here
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: Didnt work, pipeline complaining > CI=false && react-scripts build
  
  'CI' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.

Comment: @hungryMind was this on windows?

Answer (score 32):

For me the solution was:

```
env: 
  CI: false
```

Comment: Where to add this line?

Answer (score 18):

if you have to continue with the build and deploy from within GitLab CICD pipelines, you can include CI=false like so:

```
CI=false npm run build
```

or

```
unset CI
npm run build
```

Here is a complete gitlab_ci job sample:

```
build-dev:
  environment: DEV
  image: node:16
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - CI=false npm run build
  only:
    - /^devrelease-.*$/
  tags:
    - docker
```

or

```
build-dev:
  environment: DEV
  image: node:16
  stage: build
  script:
    - unset CI
    - npm install
    - npm run build
  only:
    - /^devrelease-.*$/
  tags:
    - docker
```

Answer (score 11):

In my specific case, I was using Netlify, so all I did was set the ENV vars inside Netlify's panel:

- Select **Site Settings** Tab
- Select **Build and Deploy**
- Scroll down to **Environment variables** and press **Edit Variables**
- Fill it in with Key = CI and Value = false
- Press save and trigger a new deploy

[image]

Answer (score 9):

For me replacing `npm run build` with `CI='' npm run build` worked.

Answer (score 3):

Using Azure Static web pages via GitHub repo. Adding this worked like a charm:

```yaml
env:
  CI: false
```

Just a quick note. This was applied to the `yaml` defining the CI process in GitHub actions.
The `env` element has no indentation (at the same level as the `name:`)

Note: Given all is set the same way on your side, it should be located in your GitHub repo under the tab `Actions -> Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD ->` The link to the `yaml` is right under the title (Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD )

**Azure static web-apps yaml:**

[image]

**Resource:** https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/179

Comment: Could you pleas be more specific?  Where in the yml file?

Comment: Given all is set the same way at your side it should be located in your github repo under tab Actions -> Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD  -> the link to the yaml is right under the title (Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD )

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps below and your problem would be solved:

- Select Site Settings Tab
- Select Build and Deploy
- Scroll down to Environment variables choose Edit Variables
- Fill it in with Key = CI and Value = false
- Press clear cache and redeploy

...and have fun.

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to your CI server setting (in my case it is netlify).. Follow the steps below and your problem would be solved:

Select--> `Site Settings` Tab

Select--> `Build and Deploy`

Scroll down to Environment variables choose `Edit Variables`

Fill it in with `Key = CI` and `Value = false`

Press `clear cache and redeploy`

Comment: Thank you for this -- after bashing awhile in this situation w/ Netlify, I caught on that the `warnings` were failing the build completely, then finally studied the output a bit more closely and saw mention of the flag...which the error output was a bit more robust. Thanks so much for helping unblock me ;P

Answer (score 2):

Coming from hours of googling, for me the following worked for **Azure Devops**:

In your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build": "set \"CI=false\" && react-scripts build"
}
```

Note: The **escaped quotes** are important!

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to deploy to a **windows server** or using **powershell**, you can set the environment variables like this:

```
script:
  - $env:CI="false"
  - npm run build
```

or:

```
$env:CI="false"; npm run build
```

Answer (score 1):

CI=true is needed in case you would like to process test during the deployment but it can be easily archived by setting a flag via package.json (in case in your dockerfile already set ENV CI=true you can remove it)

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "CI=true react-scripts test"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Gitlab CI job in yml file, adding below script in my job worked for me.

```
script:
- CI=false yarn run build
```

Answer (score 0):

you must fix the warnings you have in react, that's why it doesn't let you deploy

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gitlab ci & yarn and this worked for me:

```html
  script: 
    - CI=false yarn build
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was deploying a ReactJs project and I faced the CI error.
I added an environment variable to Netlify.
Variable name added was: CI and it's value was given as: false

Netlify then ignored the errors and performed the build.

Netlify add environment variable option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build ⛏️
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: 
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@main
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci --legacy-peer-deps
      - name: Build dependencies
        run: npm run build
        env: 
          CI: false  // Here I added CI = false and it worked for me
```

Add CI: false in the workflow file of github actions (main.yml probably)